# Update by query with a clause in ElasticSearch

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index where some records have a `@timestamp` of 1st Feb. There is also a field in the `_source` called `process_time` which is different for each record with same `@timestamp`.

```
{
        "_index": "elasticsearch-index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "qByop2gBw60PM5VYP0aG",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "task": "INFO",
          "@timestamp": "2019-02-01T06:04:08.365Z",
          "num_of_batches": 0,
          "batch_size": 1000,
          "process_time": "2019-02-04 06:04:04,489"
        }
},
{
        "_index": "elasticsearch-index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "qByop2gBw60PM5VYP0aG",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "task": "INFO",
          "@timestamp": "2019-02-01T06:04:08.365Z",
          "num_of_batches": 0,
          "batch_size": 1000,
          "process_time": "2019-02-05 06:04:04,489"
        }
}
```

I want to update the `@timestamp` of all records having `@timestamp` as 1st Feb to whatever is the `process_time` in that record.

How can I do this?

EDIT:

After @mysterion's answer I did the following changes as below:

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": """ctx._source['@timestamp'] = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse(ctx._source.process_time.replaceAll(",","."))""",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "@timestamp": "2019-02-01"
    }
  }
}
```

But I got the following exception:

```
"type": "class_cast_exception",
"reason": "Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.function.Function"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could utilize [Update by Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)  to update needed documents in the Elasticsearch.

```
POST index_name/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    “script”: {
        “source”: “ctx._source[‘@timestamp’] = new SimpleDateFormat(‘yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS’).parse(ctx._source.process_time)”,
        “lang”: “painless”
    },
    “query”: {
        “term”: {
            “@timestamp”: “2019-01-01T00:00:00Z”
        }
    }
}
```

You’re using replaceAll method expecting that it’s a plain Java String method, in fact - it’s not. It is

```
String replaceAll(Pattern, Function)
```

More information on Painless API reference - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference.html

Comment: Thanks this helped! But the formats of ```process_time``` and ```@timestamp``` is different. Can I overcome that. ```@timestamp``` is datetime and ```process_time ```is string. Can I parse string date into datetime in elasticsearch?

Comment: Can I use ```moment.js``` script in elasticsearch to do so?

Comment: The format of ```@timestamp``` is ```MMMM Do YYYY```

Comment: I’ve updated the answer with a parsing example, you would need potentially to alter date format a bit

Comment: Cause you painless usage is wrong :) I would recommend to remove replaceAll - since it’s not a String method, and just use pattern with comma